# Read values from Java Map using Spark Column using java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have tried below code to get `Map` values via spark column in java but getting `null` value expecting exact value from Map as per key search.

and Spark Dataset contains one column and name is `KEY` and dataset name dataset1

values in dataset :

```
KEY
1
2
```

Java Code -

```
Map<String,string> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("1","CUST1");
map1.put("2","CUST2");


dataset1.withColumn("ABCD", functions.lit(map1.get(col("KEY"))));
```

Current Output is:

```
ABCD (Column name)
null
null
```

Expected Output :

```
ABCD (Column name)
CUST1
CUST2
```

please me get this expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get this output is pretty simple. The `get` function in java can take any object as input. If that object is not in the map, the result is null.

The `lit` function in spark is used to create a single value column (all rows have the same value). e.g. `lit(1)` creates a column that takes the value 1 for each row.

Here, `map1.get(col("KEY"))` (that is executed on the driver), asks `map1` the value corresponding to a column object (not the value inside the column, the java/scala object representing the column). The map does not contain that object so the result is null. Therefore, you could as well write `lit(null)`. This is why you get a null result inside your dataset.

To solve your problem, you could wrap your map access within a UDF for instance. Something like:

```java
UserDefinedFunction map_udf = udf(new UDF1<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(String x) {
                return map1.get(x);
            }
        }, DataTypes.StringType );

spark.udf().register("map_udf", map_udf);
result.withColumn("ABCD", expr("map_udf(KEY)"));
```